# Error during handshake for tls auth by apache pulsar client on ubuntu server

Tags: openssl, apache-pulsar

I have setup the apache pulsar standalone v2.3 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
from [Run Pulsar locally](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/standalone/). It works fine without any authentication. I have tried configuring tls certificate using [security-tls-transport](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/security-tls-transport/) and [security-tls-authentication](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/security-tls-authentication/). I have modified following configs `broker.conf`,`client.conf` and `standalone.conf` as per mentioned in the link. Running pulsar using command `bin/pulsar standalone` and used below command to send message.

`bin/pulsar-client produce my-topic --messages "hello-pulsar"`

But it throws the following error

```
 [pulsar-client-io-1-1] INFO  org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConnectionPool -           
 [[id: 0x8010c4f5, L:/127.0.0.1:42840 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:6651]] 
 Connected to server
 09:47:17.686 [pulsar-client-io-1-1] WARN  
 org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ClientCnx - Error during handshake
 java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(...)(Unknown Source) 
 ~[io.netty-netty-all-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
 09:47:17.691 [pulsar-client-io-1-1] INFO  
 org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ClientCnx - [id: 0x8010c4f5, 
 L:/127.0.0.1:42840 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:6651] Disconnected
 09:47:17.692 [pulsar-client-io-1-1] WARN  
 org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ConnectionPool - [[id: 0x8010c4f5, 
 L:/127.0.0.1:42840 ! R:localhost/127.0.0.1:6651]] Connection handshake 
 failed: org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException: Connection 
 already closed
 09:47:17.692 [pulsar-client-io-1-1] WARN  
 org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.PulsarClientImpl - [my-topic] Failed to get 
 partitioned topic metadata: 
 org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException: Connection already 
 closed
 09:47:17.692 [main] ERROR org.apache.pulsar.client.cli.PulsarClientTool - 
 Error while producing messages
 09:47:17.692 [main] ERROR org.apache.pulsar.client.cli.PulsarClientTool - 
 Connection already closed
 org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException: Connection already 
 closed at 
 org.apache.pulsar.client.impl.ClientCnx.channelInactive(ClientCnx.java:204) 
 ~[org.apache.pulsar-pulsar-client-original-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at 
 io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive
 (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
 4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at 
 io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive
(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at 
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive
(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at 
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed
(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:390) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at 
io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive
   (ByteToMessageDecoder.java:355) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
  4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at 
  io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive
   (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
  4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive
  (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
  4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive
  (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
 4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed
 (ByteToMessageDecoder.java:390) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
 4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive
     (ByteToMessageDecoder.java:355) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
  4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1054) 
 ~[io.netty-netty-all-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive
  (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive
 (AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive
(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive
(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1429) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive
(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive
(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive
(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:947) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run
(AbstractChannel.java:826) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute
(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks
(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:335) ~ 
[io.netty-netty-all-4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run
(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:909) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run
(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[io.netty-netty-all- 
4.1.32.Final.jar:4.1.32.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
09:47:17.694 [main] INFO  org.apache.pulsar.client.cli.PulsarClientTool - 0 
messages successfully produced
```

Could anyone please help to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

When TLS transport encryption is enabled, you need to configure the client to use https:// and port 8443 for the web service URL, and pulsar+ssl:// and port 6651 for the broker service URL.

It looks like the client CLI tool you used, bin/pulsar-client produce my-topic --messages "hello-pulsar", doesn't use the https+ssl:// prefix. Therefore your client is trying to make a non-secure connection and is failing on the TLS negotiation step because it.

Can you try connecting using a simple Java or Python client that does specify the pulsar+ssl:// prefix?

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue, creating unit test, giving me an an exception: org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException$InvalidServiceURL: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authority component is missing in service uri : public/default. How to solve this, if I don't want to use ssl yet?

Comment: @FelixAballi  An authority is a portion of a URI. Your error suggests that it you are not providing one. See: http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-3986.txt.

Answer (score 0):

If you have made all the required changes in `broker.conf`,`client.conf` and `standalone.conf`, try running the following command to publish data:

```
bin/pulsar-client --url pulsar+ssl://127.0.0.1:6651 produce my-topic --messages "hello-pulsar"
```

Here, you need to specify the service url for the tls data.

Make sure you have the following properties added to your `standalone.conf` file :

```
tlsEnabled=true
tlsCertificateFilePath=/path/to/broker.cert.pem
tlsKeyFilePath=/path/to/broker.key-pk8.pem
tlsTrustCertsFilePath=/path/to/ca.cert.pem
brokerServicePortTls=6651
```

Also, make sure you update the the following config values in the `client.conf` file:

```
brokerServiceUrl=pulsar+ssl://127.0.0.1:6651
webServiceUrl=https://127.0.0.1:8443
tlsTrustCertsFilePath=/path/to/ca.cert.pem
```

This should work.